# What is meant by $\pi^n \bmod{1}$?

Tags: notation

In my understanding of modular arithmetic, any number $x \bmod{1}$ should be zero since any number is divisible by 1.  I'd also like to understand what is meant by "almost all real numbers $\theta > 1$".  If you can explain either one, I'll accept the answer.

You can see both expressions in context in the image below.

[image: Theorem F by Knuth]

This passage is taken from Donald E. Knuth's The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2, seminumerical algorithms, chapter 3, page 152.

Comment: $\alpha \pmod 1$ refers to the fractional part of $\alpha$.  Thus $\pi \equiv .141592... \pmod 1$, for example.

Comment: You can add that as an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: "almost all $\theta$" means that the set of $\theta$ for which the claim does not hold should have measure $0$.

Comment: @user136217 Better to delete the question if the dupe already answers it.

Comment: You nailed it all, @lulu.  If you post it as an answer, whenever, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-integer values, $x$, we can define the function $x\text{ mod } m$ (the [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)) which is equivalent to 
$$f(x,m)=x\text{ mod } m=x-m\left\lfloor\frac{x}m\right\rfloor$$
In the case $m=1$ we have
$$f(x,1)=x\text{ mod } 1=x-\lfloor x\rfloor=\{x\}$$
where $\{x\}$ denotes the [fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) of $x$.